# If points == "highest", rank = 1?

Tags: php

so recently I asked a question about using an if statment with the phrase "highest points" but I wasn't able to get anything to work. So now I am trying to make it so it says, if a user has the most amount of points, they will be rank one. Then if a user has the second most amount of points, he will be rank 2 and so on. I really am not sure how to do this so I don't really have much of a start on it but here is what I got

```
<td><?php echo ucfirst($r->username); ?></td>
<td>
    <?php
    echo ucfirst($r->points);
    if($r->points=='1') {
        echo $r->username;
    }
    ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo ucfirst($r->rank); ?></td>
<td><?php
```

Comment: you can order the results by points through sql query like   `ORDER BY points DESC`

Comment: Are your users and points stored somewhere, such as an array or database? If so, you can work with those to get proper ordering, and then you can rank them...

Comment: @Nouphal.M Yea right now I am doing that for the points, but I want it to be for the rank and rank to be based off the order of points people have

Comment: @panoptical Yes that data is being stored in a database

Comment: @Nouphal.M I'm sorry, it's kinda hard to tpye out what I am trying to say, but let me try to be more clear. So basically, I was trying to say something like "If the user has the highest ammount of points, echo a certin message." And most people were suggesting that I should just do "If points = "[insert amount here]" The problem is that there is no limit on the amount of points someone could earn so I need a way to say "If the points is the highest, then echo the message."

Comment: try removing `commas` from `'1'` just put only `1`..
and use `intval($r->points)`

Comment: So you want to display the user with highest point and display a message

Comment: @Nouphal.M essentially yes, but I want it to be in order from highest rank or points to lowest rank or points

Comment: After executing the query the results will be in the order of highest to lowest,i.e first result will be with highest point. I hope you get the point

Comment: @Nouphal.M yes this is exactly what I want, but I am not sure how to make it

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$connection = odbc_connect(connectionString);

$query = "SELECT USERS, POINTS from DB ORDER BY POINTS DESC";
$results = odbc_exec($connection,$query);

$i = 1;
while (odbc_fetch_row($results))
{
    $users[$i] = odbc_result($results,"USERS");
    $points[$i] = odbc_result($results,"POINTS");
    $rank[$i] = $i;
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Now you have 3 arrays with the rankings in order. There's no error checking here (such as if the odbc_connnect function fails), but you get the drift of it.

Comment: Right now I am getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in /home/public_html/index.php on line 54

Comment: Run `<?php phpInfo() ?>`, and look for odbc. It may or may not exist, depending on how PHP was configured when it was compiled. The configuration string will also appear there, which could tell you more information.

Comment: Do you use a mysql server? If so, `mysql_connect` could work as well, though look in your phpInfo page to confirm that first. Look for any extension that would allow you to connect to your db, really. Otherwise, you will have to configure and re-compile PHP.

Comment: Yes, I do have a mysql server. So now I am getting this error Notice: Use of undefined constant connectionString - assumed 'connectionString' in /home/public_html/index.php on line 54 
$connection = mysql_connect(connectionString);

$query = "SELECT USERS, POINTS from DB ORDER BY POINTS DESC";
$results = mysql_exec($connection,$query);

$i = 1;
while (mysql__fetch_row($results))
{
    $users[$i] = mysql_result($results,"USERS");
    $points[$i] = mysql_result($results,"POINTS");
    $rank[$i] = $i;
    $i++;
}
?>

Comment: You need to build a connectionString, which you can find how to do at http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: So would it still be mysql_exec()?

Comment: Call to undefined function mysql_exec()

Comment: Please look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
This link has everything you need to connect and read from your database.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting (which was my mistake) mysql was officially deprecated and folded into mysqli.

Comment: I am now getting this error Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given ....    $results = mysqli_stmt_execute($connection,$query);

Comment: No offense, but I really can't debug your code for you. The code I wrote above was made using odbc in mind. Looking at the examples on the PHP doc website will really help you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

for this u have to create and array from the database with the unique values(select unique(points) from table order by points desc) , that array should countain all the point in the descending order and u have to check ur rank points into that array and if rank exist in that array get the key of that element and that will be the rank of ur user among all the users...

```
$all_point_array() = (select unique(points) from table order points by desc)
   Example-> $all_point_array() = array('300','200','100');
    find value in the array
    if(in_array($r->points,$all_point_array)){
    $rank_key = array_search($r->points,$all_point_array)
    echo "your rank->".$rank_key;
    }
```

Comment: dear how can u say this answer is wrong...tell me the reason....